# displaying data using a query in a controller - cake php framework

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

Hy guys, I started to study cake php framework (version 2.0) and when i finished to read the blog tutorial i tried to do some experiments in particular my problem is "Is it possible to create a query in the model then execute it in the controller and in the end display the result of the query in a view in this way?

this is the file post.php(the model):

```
<?php

class Post extends AppModel {
    public $name='Post';
}

?>
```

this is posts_controller(the controller):

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array ('Html','Form');
    public $name = 'Posts';
    public $name = 'Articles';

    function index() {
        //$this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
        $sql="select * from posts";
        $this->set('Articles',$this->Post->query($sql));
    }
}
?>
```

The Question is if I declare for the second time $name I obtain an error from cake, in this case, Which is the correct name to set a variable that contain a posts arrays (the databse is the same of the blog tutorial) and the second question is How can I display the data obtained from the query in the index.ctp?? in the example I iterate in this way

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
```

and to obtain an element I have to write

```
<?php echo $post['Post']['title']?>
```

but in my case?

And Is it possible to declare a function tha returns a result of a query in a model, then call it in a controller and display the data in a someview.ctp?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: `$name` should be the name of the controller itself, not sure what you're trying to do with 2 names. Just stick with "Posts".

Question 2:
You're probably just confusing matters here by referring to posts as articles..

Best thing for you to do is change this:

```
$this->set('Articles',$this->Post->query($sql));
```

to

```
$this->set('posts',$this->Post->query($sql));
```

Then the references in the template will work the same. What's happening here is when calling the `$this->set` method you're making the data accessible to the template in a variable called $posts. So what you currently have:

```
$this->set('Articles',$this->Post->query($sql));
```

Will make the data accessible to the template in a variable called `$Articles`.

Comment: Question 1: just leave out `$name` (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045324/does-cakephp-2-0-still-need-name-declared-in-the-model)) :)