# Does CakePHP 2.0 still need $name declared in the model?

Tags: cakephp

I was under the impression that we had to declare - public $name = 'ModelName'; in the model exclusively for PHP4.  Now that cakephp no longer supports PHP4 I thought there no longer needs to be $name declaration in the model.  The cookbook still has instructions to include it though: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html

The models work fine without it from what I see.  What is it used for, and why do I need it?

Thanks!

Comment: N. B. you also don't need to define `Model::name` in CakePHP 1.3 if you are running PHP 5+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a leftover from the earlier cookbooks. See for example http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#name, it mentions PHP4 compatibility even though CakePHP 2.0 no longer works with PHP4.

So, to answer your question: no, you do not have to declare `$name` in your models.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need need $name in any of your classes.
not even in 1.3 (who still uses php4 anyway^^), but especially not in 2.0.

I wrote an enhanced UpgradeShell which removes those unnecessary chunks from all class files:
http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2117-improvements-for-20-upgrade-shell
but this new command I didnt yet add to the ticket patch.

I called the command "name"

```
/**
 * Remove name (lib, controller, model, view, component, behavior, helper, fixture)
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function name() {
    $libs = App::path('Lib');
    $views = App::path('views');
    $controllers = App::path('controllers');
    $components = App::path('components');
    $models = App::path('models');
    $helpers = App::path('helpers');
    $behaviors = App::path('behaviors');

    $this->_paths = array_merge($libs, $views, $controllers, $components, $models, $helpers, $behaviors);
    $this->_paths[] = TESTS . 'Fixture' . DS;

    if (!empty($this->params['plugin'])) {
        $pluginPath = App::pluginPath($this->params['plugin']);
        $this->_paths = array(
            $pluginPath . 'Lib' . DS,
            $pluginPath . 'Controller' . DS,
            $pluginPath . 'Controller' . DS . 'Component' .DS,
            $pluginPath . 'View' . DS,
            $pluginPath . 'View' . DS . 'Helper' . DS,
            $pluginPath . 'Model' . DS,
            $pluginPath . 'Model' . DS . 'Behavior' . DS,
            $pluginPath . 'Test' . DS . 'Fixture' . DS,
            $pluginPath . 'libs' . DS,
            $pluginPath . 'controllers' . DS,
            $pluginPath . 'controllers' . DS . 'components' .DS,
            $pluginPath . 'views' . DS,
            $pluginPath . 'views' . DS . 'helpers' .DS,
            $pluginPath . 'models' . DS,
            $pluginPath . 'models' . DS . 'behaviors' . DS,
            $pluginPath . 'tests' . DS . 'fixtures' . DS,
        );
    }

    $patterns = array(
        array(
            'remove var $name = ...;',
            '/\bvar\s*\$name\s*=\s*(.*);/',
            ''
        ),
        array(
            'remove public $name = ...;',
            '/\bpublic\s*\$name\s*=\s*(.*);/',
            ''
        ),
    );
    $this->_filesRegexpUpdate($patterns);
}
```